# Is the Plural of “Übelkeit” “Tabellen”?

Tags: meaning, abbreviation, dictionary, online-resource

Am I totally missunderstanding the abrreviations of “Pl. s.”?

Or do they actually mean on the leo.org page [“Übelkeit Plural siehe Tabelle”](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=%C3%9Cbelkeit&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on&pos=0)?

If I understand the abbreviation correctly, what exactly do they want to tell me with that? I would be totally confused in case *Tabellen* is the plural of *Übelkeit* I don’t even see a notable connection bwtween these words at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to how to interpret a software with unintuitiv UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site says:

> die **Übelkeit** *Pl. s. Tabellen*

*Pl.* is the abbreviation for *Plural* and *s.* is the abbreviation for *siehe.* You could parse this in two ways:

1. Check the entry of *Tabellen* for the plural of *Übelkeit*
2. Check the tables for the plural of *Übelkeit*

I was confused, too, at first, and clicked on *Tabellen*, which brought me to an entry for *Tabellen* (tables) — not what I wanted. Then, I noticed a little white rectangular symbol with some blue lines in it, to the left of the *play* symbol that you can probably use to listen to the word. Click that, and a table opens which contains forms of *Übelkeit* in all cases and numbers.

I don’t know why they did it that way, beause it’s *Übelkeit* (inv.) in all singular cases and *Übelkeiten* (inv.) in all plural cases.

---

Note that *Übelkeit* is generally only used in singular, although the plural form does exist.

Comment: Hint: there could be a connection between your lat two sentences ;) To quote LEO: Erläuterung: Als Abstraktum nur im Singular, in Form von konkreten Exemplaren auch im Plural

Comment: @CarstenS Welche zwei Sätze? »Es gibt nur *Übelkeit* und *Übelkeiten*« und »der Singular ist wesentlich häufiger« oder andre zwei?

Comment: Ich meinte, das *why* könnte vielleicht dadurch erklärt werden, dass sie auch meinten, eine *Note* wäre nötig.

Comment: @CarstenS aaah, so meinst du das. Das wäre sogar möglich.

Comment: Es kann natürlich auch sein, dass da keiner etwas gedacht hat. Ich bin kein LEO-Fan.